# SQL Server 2014 : slow stored procedure execution time

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, sqlperformance

I have the following table structure:

`AuditUserMethods`:

```
+---------------+---------------+----------+
|  ColumnName   |   DataType    | Nullable |
+---------------+---------------+----------+
| Id            | INT           | NOT NULL |
| CreatedDate   | DATETIME      | NOT NULL |
| ApiMethodName | NVARCHAR(MAX) | NOT NULL |
| Request       | NVARCHAR(MAX) | NOT NULL |
| Result        | NVARCHAR(MAX) | NOT NULL |
| Method_Id     | INT           | NOT NULL |
| User_Id       | INT           | NULL     |
+---------------+---------------+----------+
```

`AuditUserMethodErrorCodes`:

```
+--------------------+----------+----------+
|     ColumnName     | DataType | Nullable |
+--------------------+----------+----------+
| Id                 | INT      | NOT NULL |
| AuditUserMethod_Id | INT      | NOT NULL |
| ErrorCode          | INT      | NOT NULL |
+--------------------+----------+----------+
```

The `ID` is the PK in both tables. There is a one to many relationship. An `AuditUserMethod` can have many `AuditUserMethodErrorCodes`. Hence the FK `AuditUserMethod_Id`.

There are two nonclustered indexes on both the `AuditUserMethod_Id` and `CreatedDate` in the `AuditUserMethods` table.

The purpose of the procedure is to return a paginated result set based on filters. The `@PageSize` determines how many rows to return and `@PageIndex` determines which page to return. All other variables are for filtering.

Three result sets are returned.

1. Contains the the `AuditUserMethods` detail
2. Contains the `AuditUserMethodErrorCodes` detail
3. Contains the total rows found (i.e. if the page size was 1000 and there were 5000 rows that matched all the criteria, this would return 5000).

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [api].[Audit_V1_GetAuditDetails]
(
    @Users XML = NULL,
    @Methods XML = NULL,
    @ErrorCodes XML = NULL,
    @FromDate DATETIME = NULL,
    @ToDate DATETIME = NULL,
    @PageSize INT = 5,
    @PageIndex INT = 0
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @UserIds            TABLE   (Id INT)
    DECLARE @MethodNames        TABLE   (Name NVARCHAR(256))
    DECLARE @ErrorCodeIds       TABLE   (Id INT)

    DECLARE @FilterUsers        BIT = 0
    DECLARE @FilterMethods      BIT = 0
    DECLARE @FilterErrorCodes   BIT = 0

    INSERT @UserIds
       SELECT
           x.y.value('.', 'int')
       FROM 
           @Users.nodes('Ids/x/@i') AS x (y)

    INSERT @MethodNames
       SELECT
           x.y.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(256)')
       FROM 
           @Methods.nodes('ArrayOfString/string') AS x (y)

    INSERT @ErrorCodeIds
       SELECT
           x.y.value('.', 'int')
       FROM 
           @ErrorCodes.nodes('Ids/x/@i') AS x (y)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 0 FROM @UserIds)
       SET @FilterUsers = 1

    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 0 FROM @MethodNames)
       SET @FilterMethods = 1

    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 0 FROM @ErrorCodeIds)
       SET @FilterErrorCodes = 1

    DECLARE @StartRow INT = @PageIndex * @Pagesize

    DECLARE @PageDataResults TABLE (Id INT,
                                    CreatedDate DATETIME,
                                    ApiMethodName NVARCHAR(256), 
                                    Request NVARCHAR(MAX),
                                    Result NVARCHAR(MAX),
                                    MethodId INT,
                                    UserId INT,
                                    TotalRows INT);

    WITH PageData AS
    (
        SELECT
            id AS id
            , createddate AS createddate
            , apimethodname AS apimethodname
            , request AS request
            , result AS result
            , method_id AS method_id
            , user_id AS user_id
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY createddate DESC, id DESC) AS row_number
            , COUNT(*) OVER() as TotalRows
        FROM 
            dbo.AuditUserMethods AS aum
        WHERE 
           (@FromDate IS NULL OR 
            (@FromDate IS NOT NULL AND aum.createddate > @FromDate))
           AND (@ToDate IS NULL OR 
                (@ToDate IS NOT NULL AND aum.createddate < @ToDate))
           AND (@FilterUsers = 0 OR 
                (@FilterUsers = 1 AND aum.user_id IN (SELECT Id FROM @UserIds)))
           AND (@FilterMethods = 0 OR 
                (@FilterMethods = 1 AND aum.ApiMethodName IN (SELECT Name FROM @MethodNames)))
           AND (@FiltererRorCodes = 0 OR 
                    (@FiltererRorCodes = 1 
                     AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                 FROM AuditUserMethodErrorCodes e
                                 WHERE e.AuditUserMethod_Id = aum.Id
                                   AND e.ErrorCode IN (SELECT Id FROM @ErrorCodeIds)
                                )
                    )
               )
    )

    INSERT @PageDataResults
        SELECT TOP (@Pagesize)
            PageData.id AS id
            , PageData.createddate AS createddate
            , PageData.apimethodname AS apimethodname
            , PageData.request AS request
            , PageData.result AS result
            , PageData.method_id AS method_id
            , PageData.user_id AS user_id
            , PageData.TotalRows AS totalrows
         FROM 
             PageData
         WHERE 
             PageData.row_number > @StartRow
         ORDER BY 
             PageData.createddate DESC

    SELECT 
        Id, CreatedDate, ApiMethodName, Request, Result, MethodId, UserId
    FROM 
        @PageDataResults

    SELECT 
        aumec.AuditUserMethod_Id, aumec.ErrorCode
    FROM 
        @PageDataResults ps
    INNER JOIN 
        AuditUserMethodErrorCodes aumec ON ps.Id = aumec.AuditUserMethod_Id

    SELECT TOP 1 
        TotalRowsNumberOfReturnedAuditEntries 
    FROM @PageDataResults
END
```

The `AuditUserMethods` table contains 500,000 rows and the `AuditUserMethodErrorCodes` contains 67843 rows.

I am executing the procedure with the following parameters:

```
EXEC [api].[Audit_V1_GetAuditDetails]   @Users = N'<Ids><x i="1" /></Ids>'
                                        ,@Methods = NULL
                                        ,@ErrorCodes = N'<Ids />'
                                        ,@FromDate = '2015-02-15 07:18:59.613'
                                        ,@ToDate = '2015-07-02 08:18:59.613'
                                        ,@Pagesize = 5000
                                        ,@PageIndex = 0
```

The stored procedure takes just over 2 seconds to execute and return 5000 rows. I need this stored procedure to run much faster and I'm not sure how to improve it.

According to the actual execution plan. It is the CTE that is taking up 99% relative to the batch. Within the CTE, it is the Sort that is taking up 95% of the cost:

[image: Actual Execution Plan]

Comment: Is the execution quick the first time (after the server restarts or after you run `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`) then slows right down when you change the parameters? Or, is it just slow?

Comment: It seems to be fairly consistent even after freeing the proc cache.

Comment: I've finally done editing my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31202079/659190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by declaring a couple table parameter types.

```
CREATE TYPE [api].[IdSet] AS TABLE
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL
);
```

and,

```
CREATE TYPE [api].[StringSet] AS TABLE
(
    [Value] NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
```

Then I'd change the signature of the store procedure to use them.

**Note** I'd also return the total count as an output parameter rather than as a separate result set.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [api].[Audit_V2_GetAuditDetails]
(
    @userIds [api].[IdSet] READONLY,
    @methodNames [api].[StringSet] READONLY,
    @errorCodeIds [api].[IdSet] READONLY,
    @fromDate DATETIME = NULL,
    @toDate DATETIME = NULL,
    @pageSize INT = 5,
    @pageIndex INT = 0,
    @totalCount BIGINT OUTPUT
)
```

I know you may still need to do the XML extraction but it will help the query planner if you do it outside the SP.

Now, in the SP, I would not use the `@PageDataResults` I'd get just the ids for the page. I wouldn't use the CTE either, that is not helping in this scenario.

I'd simplify the query and run it once to aggregate the total count, then if that is greater than 0, run the same query again to return just the page of ids. The main body of the query will have been cached internally by the server.

Additionally, Id' do the paging with the `OFFSET` and `FETCH` extensions to [`ORDER BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx),

There are a number of logical simplifications that I outline below,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [api].[Audit_V2_GetAuditDetails]
    (
        @userIds [api].[IdSet] READONLY,
        @methodNames [api].[StringSet] READONLY,
        @errorCodeIds [api].[IdSet] READONLY,
        @fromDate DATETIME = NULL,
        @toDate DATETIME = NULL,
        @pageSize INT = 5,
        @pageIndex INT = 0,
        @totalCount BIGINT OUTPUT
    )
AS

DECLARE @offset INT = @pageSize * @pageIndex; 
DECLARE @filterUsers BIT = 0;
DECLARE @filterMethods BIT = 0;
DECLARE @filterErrorCodes BIT = 0;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM @userIds)
    SET @filterUsers = 1;
IF EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM @methodNames)
    SET @filterMethods = 1;
IF EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM @errorCodeIds)
    SET @filterErrorCodes = 1;

SELECT
            @totalCount = COUNT_BIG(*)
     FROM
            [dbo].[AuditUserMethods] [aum]
         LEFT JOIN
            @userIds [U]
                ON [U].[Id] = [aum].[user_id]
         LEFT JOIN
            @methodName [M]
                ON [M].[Value] = [aum].[ApiMethodName]
    WHERE
            (
               @fromDate IS NULL
            OR
               [aum].[createddate] > @fromDate
            )
        AND
            (
               @toDate IS NULL
            OR
               [aum].[createddate] < @toDate
            )
        AND
            (
                @filterUsers = 0
            OR
                [U].[Id] IS NOT NULL
            (
        AND
            (
                @filterMethods = 0
            OR
                [M].[Value] IS NOT NULL
            (
        AND
            (
                @filterErrorCodes = 0
            OR 
                (
                    EXISTS(
                        SELECT
                                    1
                            FROM
                                    [dbo].[AuditUserMethodErrorCodes] [e]
                                JOIN
                                    @errorCodeIds [ec]
                                       ON [ec].[Id] = [e].[ErrorCode]
                            WHERE
                                    [e].[AuditUserMethod_Id] = [aum].[Id])
                );

DECLARE @pageIds [api].[IdSet];

IF @totalCount > 0
INSERT @pageIds
SELECT
            [aum].[id]
     FROM
            [dbo].[AuditUserMethods] [aum]
         LEFT JOIN
            @userIds [U]
                ON [U].[Id] = [aum].[user_id]
         LEFT JOIN
            @methodName [M]
                ON [M].[Value] = [aum].[ApiMethodName]
    WHERE
            (
               @fromDate IS NULL
            OR
               [aum].[createddate] > @fromDate
            )
        AND
            (
               @toDate IS NULL
            OR
               [aum].[createddate] < @toDate
            )
        AND
            (
                @filterUsers = 0
            OR
                [U].[Id] IS NOT NULL
            (
        AND
            (
                @filterMethods = 0
            OR
                [M].[Value] IS NOT NULL
            (
        AND
            (
                @filterErrorCodes = 0
            OR 
                (
                    EXISTS(
                        SELECT
                                    1
                            FROM
                                    [dbo].[AuditUserMethodErrorCodes] [e]
                                JOIN
                                    @errorCodeIds [ec]
                                       ON [ec].[Id] = [e].[ErrorCode]
                            WHERE
                                    [e].[AuditUserMethod_Id] = [aum].[Id])
                )
    ORDER BY
            [aum].[createddate] DESC,
            [aum].[id] DESC
        OFFSET @offset ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY;

SELECT 
            [aum].[Id],
            [aum].[CreatedDate],
            [aum].[ApiMethodName],
            [aum].[Request],
            [aum].[Result],
            [aum].[MethodId],
            [aum].[UserId]
    FROM
            [dbo].[AuditUserMethods] [aum]
    JOIN
            @pageIds [i]
                ON [i].[Id] = [aum].[id] 
ORDER BY
            [aum].[createddate] DESC,
            [aum].[id] DESC;

SELECT 
            [aumec].[AuditUserMethod_Id],
            [aumec].[ErrorCode]
    FROM
            [dbo].[AuditUserMethodErrorCodes] [aumec]
        JOIN
            @pageIds [i]
                ON [i].[Id] = [aumec].[AuditUserMethod_Id];

/* The total count is an output parameter */
RETURN 0;
```

If this doesn't improve things enough, you'll need to look at the query plan and consider what indices would be optimal.

***Caveat*** All the code is written off the cuff, so, while the ideas are right the syntax may not be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```
(@FromDate IS NULL OR 
            (@FromDate IS NOT NULL AND aum.createddate > @FromDate))
```

is the same as

```
(@FromDate IS NULL OR  aum.createddate > @FromDate)
```

try something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [api].[Audit_V1_GetAuditDetails]
(
    @Users XML = NULL,
    @Methods XML = NULL,
    @ErrorCodes XML = NULL,
    @FromDate DATETIME = NULL,
    @ToDate DATETIME = NULL,
    @PageSize INT = 5,
    @PageIndex INT = 0
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @UserIds            TABLE   (Id INT)
    DECLARE @MethodNames        TABLE   (Name NVARCHAR(256))
    DECLARE @ErrorCodeIds       TABLE   (Id INT)

    INSERT @UserIds
       SELECT
           x.y.value('.', 'int')
       FROM 
           @Users.nodes('Ids/x/@i') AS x (y)

    INSERT @MethodNames
       SELECT
           x.y.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(256)')
       FROM 
           @Methods.nodes('ArrayOfString/string') AS x (y)

    INSERT @ErrorCodeIds
       SELECT
           x.y.value('.', 'int')
       FROM 
           @ErrorCodes.nodes('Ids/x/@i') AS x (y)

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 0 FROM @UserIds)
       INSERT INTO @UserIds values (-1)

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 0 FROM @MethodNames)
       INSERT INTO @MethodNames values ('empty')

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 0 FROM @ErrorCodeIds)
       INSERT INTO @ErrorCodeIds values (-1)

    IF @FromDate is null 
       @FromDate = '1/1/1900'

    IF @ToDate is null 
       @ToDate = '1/1/2079'

    DECLARE @StartRow INT = @PageIndex * @Pagesize

    DECLARE @PageDataResults TABLE (Id INT,
                                    CreatedDate DATETIME,
                                    ApiMethodName NVARCHAR(256), 
                                    Request NVARCHAR(MAX),
                                    Result NVARCHAR(MAX),
                                    MethodId INT,
                                    UserId INT,
                                    TotalRows INT);

    WITH PageData AS
    (
        SELECT
            id AS id
            , createddate AS createddate
            , apimethodname AS apimethodname
            , request AS request
            , result AS result
            , method_id AS method_id
            , user_id AS user_id
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY createddate DESC, id DESC) AS row_number
            , COUNT(*) OVER() as TotalRows
        FROM 
            dbo.AuditUserMethods AS aum
        JOIN @UserIds
          ON (aum.user_id = @UserIds.ID OR @UserIds.ID = -1)
         AND aum.createddate > @FromDate
         AND aum.createddate < @ToDate
        JOIN @MethodNames 
          ON aum.ApiMethodName = @MethodNames.Name 
          OR @MethodNames.Name = 'empty'
        JOIN AuditUserMethodErrorCodes e
          on e.AuditUserMethod_Id = aum.Id 
        JOIN @ErrorCodeIds 
          ON e.ErrorCode = @ErrorCodeIds.ID 
          OR @ErrorCodeIds.ID = -1
    )
```

Comment: I like that idea. It looks a lot cleaner in the WHERE clauses. As for the OR statements being the same. I wasn't sure whether SQL supports short circuited operations or not.

Comment: Problem with the where is you can get a big join and then filter.  The idea is to help the query optimizer filter early.  It is not really a short circuit - the compare to null would return a false anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by giving your CTE some sort of index, which can be accomplished by the following - refer to the /**/ for the "changed lines":

```
WITH PageData AS
(
    SELECT
/**/    TOP 100 PERCENT                                                                 
        id                                              AS id
        ,createddate                                    AS createddate
        ,apimethodname                                  AS apimethodname
        ,request                                        AS request
        ,result                                         AS result
        ,method_id                                      AS method_id
        ,user_id                                        AS user_id
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY createddate DESC, id DESC) AS row_number
        ,COUNT(*) OVER() as TotalRows
    FROM dbo.AuditUserMethods AS aum
    WHERE (@FromDate IS NULL OR (@FromDate IS NOT NULL AND aum.createddate > @FromDate))
    AND (@ToDate IS NULL OR (@ToDate IS NOT NULL AND aum.createddate < @ToDate))
    AND (@FilterUsers = 0 OR (@FilterUsers = 1 AND aum.user_id IN (SELECT Id FROM @UserIds)))
    AND (@FilterMethods = 0 OR (@FilterMethods = 1 AND aum.ApiMethodName IN (SELECT Name FROM @MethodNames)))
    AND 
        (
            @FiltererRorCodes = 0 OR 
                (
                    @FiltererRorCodes = 1 AND EXISTS 
                        (
                            SELECT 1
                            FROM AuditUserMethodErrorCodes e
                            WHERE e.AuditUserMethod_Id = aum.Id
                            AND e.ErrorCode IN (SELECT Id FROM @ErrorCodeIds)
                        )
                )
        )
/**/ORDER BY 
/**/    PageData.createddate 
/**/    ,PageData.row_number
)
```

I would also experiment with changing the "order" of the order by on the CTE between createddate and then row_number and then row_number first and then createddate .

You are then handing the CTE off to the next process with it already being in the order it expects.  It may speed things up.  The TOP 100 PERCENT is required for the ORDER BY.

Comment: Tricks like these are called "intermediate materialized CTE", and require an extra sort. Personally I prefer "materialization" in a (local) temporary table. Added benefit is that these provide statistics and in some instances your query can benefit from adding an index (or multiple).

Comment: @TT I do sometimes go the table variable route, especially when SQL gives you the lazy loading performance confusion, where table variables or temp tables are done when you expect them to be.  In this case, I think only a single "index" is required, so the CTE may work well and requires very little rework.  Thanks for you comment.

Comment: ` TOP 100 PERCENT` will be optimised out anyway and have no effect.

Comment: @MartinSmith I have used this "trick" extensively and if definitely works as expected.  The order by for the CTE speeds up the query, but requires the TOP 100 PERCENT, as you will get a "Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified."

Comment: It's been optimised out since 2005 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/24/560396.aspx

Comment: @MartinSmith In a standard query "Yes", but in this case, to force the CTE to effect the "Order By", you need to specify TOP 100 Percent.   Alternatively, how would you sort the CTE (at creation time)?

Comment: And it doesn't work. See http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/10/03/exploring-the-secrets-of-intermediate-materialization.aspx

Comment: @MartinSmith I see what is said in a 2006 article, but as of SQL 2012 and what myself and countless others see, is different.  Maybe the optimizing team has changed their mind.  I am incredulous of the statement, as I have seen this work with my own eyes.  I often optimize old queries at work, when I need to make new changes.

Comment: Test it. You will not be able to generate an execution plan any different with `TOP 100 PERCENT ... ORDER BY` than without it.